# how permanently change php version in imac?

Tags: php, macos

Everytime I open my mac, the php version goes back to 7.0. I run the code 
`source ~/.bash_profile` to refresh it and goes to 7.2. Now when I open my mamp pro 4.3 with php7.2, my version goes back to 7.0 if I check it on terminal with `php -v`

this is my ~/.bash_profile:

> alias showFiles='defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles
>   YES; killall Finder /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app' alias
>   hideFiles='defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles NO;
>   killall Finder /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app' export
>   PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin export
>   PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH export
>   PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1/bin:$PATH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about use brew? I remove the original php 7.1 from macOS 10.13 and upgrade it to 7.2. It's really simple manage the installed programs on Mac with brew, take a look: https://github.com/ibrunotome/macOS-switchblade/blob/master/install.sh

Comment: I did `brew install php72-pcntl` after that `brew unlink php71`, seems to be working after I restart Mamp. I still have to test to restart my computer. Ill let you know later.

Comment: Its now coming back to `php7.1`. But I `unlink 7.1` but its says not found.

Comment: And what about the result from php -v on the terminal? If was 7.2, I suggest to not use mamp and run the server from the terminal with `php -S localhost:8000` or `php artisan serve` if you are using laravel for example.

Comment: Is there any file like bash is loading 7.1?